# What is the typical value of a scope's blocking capacitor used in AC coupling?

Tags: oscilloscope, coupling

I find many information about what AC coupling is about as following:

[image]

But not a single of them mentions the typical value of the blocking capacitor used in a scope's AC coupling. No quantitative information.

Considering a scope in 1x setting, input resistance of a scope is typically 1Meg. But what is the typical value of the scope's blocking cap. used in AC coupling? And why?

Comment: Why not measure it? Get a square wave generator, set it to a very long period. Measure the output with your scope, and you'll be able to find the capacitor value for your scope specifically.

Comment: Because even though I make a measurement, I will remain paranoid if my measurement was correct. I need a typical value so that I can be sure.

Comment: Measuring it is perfectly valid. You can also measure it with a capacitance meter if you have one. I think you can also use the capacitive voltage divider rule to measure it if you add an external series cap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were designing a scope and you wanted less than say 1% error measuring 60 Hz into 1 MOhm impedance, yet not have to deal with slow decay times from probing DC levels with small AC signals you would want the response time as quick as possible.

So what is that optimum frequency?

I would choose f-3dB slightly less than a 10 Hz HPF breakpoint for AC coupled Scope input.

Thus you can figure this out yourself, or not... ;)

C = 1/(2πfR) = 1/(6.28*10*1M)= 0.0156 uF or slightly more 0.02uF as in agreement with Sam and Barry.  But it depends on th designer's two criteria I defined up front. decay time and attenuation error at 50/60Hz.

Comment: sorry but 022uF together with 1Meg input resistance of the scope makes around 724Hz cutoff. But I see attenuation in AC coupling for sinusoidal inputs only under 10Hz. Why is that so?

Comment: check your calculations

Comment: oh you are right it makes 7Hz. I was using a website calculator that lead me wrong. thanks.

Comment: that's the problem with calculators, there is still human input error

Answer (score 1):

> what is the typical value of the scope's blocking cap. used in AC coupling?

As examples, two values from old-ish 100MHz Tektronix 'scopes are:

0.019uF and 0.022uF

Answer (score 0):

The 50 MHz Tektronix 453 oscilloscope has an input coupling capacitor of 0.1 uF.  The 100 MHz Tektronix 465B oscilloscope has an input coupling capacitor of 0.019 uF.